# Regex mysql for any term

Tags: php, mysql

I need to replace any div and any term inside div on my code.

in PHP is like this:

```
$newbody = str_replace('<div(.*?)>','',$body);
```

But in Mysql i have this structure to replace words:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, '<div(.*?)>', '');# <- thats wrong
```

thanks guys.

Comment: I don't think you really want to do that.

Comment: Is not the same answer

Comment: I need to do that because I want to clean my bd from all DIV tags

Comment: MySQL regexes can only match. they do not replace.

Answer (score 3):

There's not such thing as MySQL replacement with regular expressions, but you could try [this](https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp)